# Linear momentum of a system remains conserved, but with respect to which frame of reference?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, momentum, conservation-laws, inertial-frames

I have studied that linear momentum of a system remains conserved. But i can't figure out with which reference of frame it is conserved. Is it conserved with respect to system reference frame or in a reference frame attached to one of body of a system or both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is conserved in any ***inertial*** reference frame.

A frame attached to one of the bodies, or even the system reference frame, are not necessarily inertial - non-inertial frames are sometimes *easier* to work with than inertial frames.

Comment: True, but a frame attached to one of the bodies will never be inertial, so momentum conservation will not hold in such a frame.  (disclaimer:  ignoring cases where there is no interaction between the particles, no collision)